# How can I stay informed of comments posted on my questions?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Whenever i post questions then i know that the answers i can see from my user page by clicking recent. But for comments i have to click on every questions and then see. they are are not sorted if i click on recent.

Is there any way that i can see the comments posted in descending order or at least get informed when comment is made

Answer (score 2):

The envelope icon informs you about comments to your own questions/answers. You get no information about comments to answers of your questions (for now).